# Unable to find column with logical name: propertymasterfk in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(mastertable) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

This is project is created spring boot with hibernate and mySql,
::Scenario ::
In a apartment details going to store in parent table,the sub table contains block,floor,flat startingand ending numbers.
[Click Here to see form sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gru6w.png)

I created 2 tables ,which is i need to do relationship parent table with child table,in parent table i given

> @OneToMany
>   @JoinColumn(name="propertyid",referencedColumnName="propertymasterfk")
>   private List blockListPropSub;

This column is need to do relation ship with

> @Column(name="propertymasterfk")
>   private int propertymasterfk;

Here is a complete code snippets
Parent Table **EntPropertyMaster**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Property_Master")
public class EntPropertyMaster implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6162594257264775391L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="propertyid")
    private int property_id;

    @NotNull
    private String property_name;

    @NotNull
    private String address1;

    @NotNull
    @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(15) default'None'")
    private String address2;

    @NotNull
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    private String state;

    @NotNull
    private String country;

    @NotNull
    private int zipcode;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="propertyid",referencedColumnName="propertymasterfk")
    private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub;
}
```

Here This is Child table **EntPropertySub**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="propertysub")
public class EntPropertySub implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 810618405796553525L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="propertysubpk")
    private int propertySub_pk;

    @Column(name="propertymasterfk")
    private int propertymasterfk;

    @NotNull
    private String blockname;

    @NotNull
    private int floors;

    @NotNull
    private String flatstart;

    private String flatend;
}
```

While i execute The Error Says **Unable to map collection com.vfraternity.process.entity.EntPropertyMaster.blockListPropSub**

Here is a compete Error Log

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2017-10-20 12:35:43.638 ERROR 17844 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection
>   com.vfraternity.process.entity.EntPropertyMaster.blockListPropSub     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]   at
>   com.vfraternity.VfSpringBootMain.main(VfSpringBootMain.java:12)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to
>   map collection
>   com.vfraternity.process.entity.EntPropertyMaster.blockListPropSub     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1604)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:871)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:786)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:358)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]   ... 16 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find
>   column with logical name: propertymasterfk in
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Table(property_master) and its related
>   supertables and secondary tables  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:831)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:243)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1594)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   ... 31 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find
>   column with logical name: propertymasterfk in
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Table(property_master) and its related
>   supertables and secondary tables  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:826)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   ... 33 common frames
>   omitted

Please any one help to solve this..

Comment: Don't store foreign keys of other entities. Use a bidirectional OneToMany association: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Tanks for reply ,but it is not working it requires joincolumn to identify..Error Log  Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like  '@JoinTable' or '@JoinColumn: 'com.vfraternity.process.entity.EntPropertyMaster.blockListPropSub

Comment: Read the error message, and thus delete the JoinColumn on the list. Read the documentation I linked too, carefully. The JoinColumn must be on the many site.

Answer (score 1):

This changes will work...
For Parent Table

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="propertysub",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="propertyid"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="propertysubpk"))
    private List<EntPropertySub> blockListPropSub = new ArrayList<EntPropertySub>();
```

For Child table

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)     
private EntPropertyMaster propertymasterfk = new EntPropertyMaster();
```